# Using FindRoot in a Table of Iterations

Tags: list-manipulation, equation-solving

So I have a tanh curve and a straight line that cross at the point:

```
msol=FindRoot[Tanh[x] == (T/Tc03) x, {x, 1}]
```

This gives me the roots that I need at a certain temperature, T. I now need these roots to iteratively get a value for chi at different temperatures between 0K and 4K. I am currently using a Table to do this like so:

```
(*constants*)

mu = 6.0281*10^-23;
Tc03 = 0.00459;
k = 1.3806488*10^-23;

(*calculation*) 

chi = Table[(mu^2 Sech^2[(Tc03/(mu T)) FindRoot[
     Tanh[x] == (T/Tc03) x, {x, 1}]])/(k T (1 - (Tc03/
      T) Sech^2[(Tc03/(mu T)) FindRoot[
        Tanh[x] == (T/Tc03) x, {x, 1}]])), {T, 1*10^-6, 4, 1}]
```

This gives me the values but where the FindRoot is, it says x->y where y is the root at that temperature, i.e. not numerical values that I can plot. The aim is to plot T vs chi iteratively and then join up the dots and get the form of the curve.

The table also does not tell me what value of T the iteration has taken place at, which I need for the plot.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `FindRoot[]` returns replacement rules. You need to understand how to use them to program in Mathematica

Comment: See for example here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18706/193 and please read all the answers therein

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression for `chi` should be rewritten as

```
chi = 
  Table[
    With[{
      val = Sech[Tc03/(mu T) ((T/Tc03) x /. 
              FindRoot[Tanh[x] == (T/Tc03) x, {x, 1}])]},
      (mu^2 val^2)/(k T (1 - (Tc03/T) val^2))], 
    {T, 1.*10^-6, 4., 1.}]
```

> ```
> {-5.73535*10^-20, 2.64408*10^-22, 1.319*10^-22, 8.78661*10^-23}
> ```

However, `FindRoot` will always find the root `0` at `x = 0`, `val` will always evaluate to `1.`, so I question your formulation of your problem.